# Embed Connected WebParts in Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I created 2 connected webparts (provider/consumer).  I now want to insert the Provider into my masterpage and the Consumer in a webpart zone on a page.  Every example I've found talks about connecting them through the UI webpart properties area.  But since 1 will be on the masterpage and the other added to a zone, I do not have that luxury.  Does anyone know how to set these properties in the xml properties?

For example, I have this custom webpart as a Provider:

```
<TeamsiteDropdownlistWebPart:TeamsiteDropdownlistWebPart 
runat="server" 
XmlQuery="" 
Description="My Visual WebPart" 
SiteUrl="http://spdev01:25706" 
Title="TeamsiteDropdownlistWebPart" 
ListName="Teamsite List" 
AllowConnect="true"
__MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" 
__WebPartId="{e4e8cd86-5b32-46bc-a8dc-341c06354787}" 
WebPart="true" 
__designer:IsClosed="false" id="g_e4e8cd86_5b32_46bc_a8dc_341c06354787">
</TeamsiteDropdownlistWebPart:TeamsiteDropdownlistWebPart>
```

I'm not sure what to do beyond this point.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We need SPLimitedWebPartManager to connect the Web parts with ASP.NET style interfaces. The steps for this are:

1. Get the SPLimitedWebPartManager instance on the page;
2. Get the provider and consumer Web parts need to be connected;
3. Get the connection points for the provider and consumer Web parts;
4. Connect them using SPConnectWebParts method. If necessary, certain transforming needs to be in place for compatible interfaces

Your code:

```
SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;      
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);      
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart provider= mgr.WebParts["TeamsiteDropdownlistWebPart"];   
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart consumer= mgr.WebParts["ConsumerWebPart"];  
ConsumerConnectionPoint addConsumerConnPoint = mgr.GetConsumerConnectionPoints(consumer)["AddressConsumer_ot"];   
ProviderConnectionPoint addProviderConnPoint = mgr.GetProviderConnectionPoints(provider)["AddressProvider_ot"];      
mgr.SPConnectWebParts(provider, addProviderConnPoint, consumer, addConsumerConnPoint);
```

This came from http://www.dhirendrayadav.com/2010/06/connecting-web-parts-programmatically.html, and seems to be the consensus.  I don't have a vanilla environment to test on unfortunately,